# i have 3 post in one page how to give them unique class in wordpress?<div class="titl">what is solution?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have 3 post in one page how to give them unique class in wordpress?given class is attempt to all the 3post..what is solution?  
    
    
    ID;
     ?>
    //new class
    
    
    //title of the class

```
<?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is there html in the title of the post?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the_ID() function

```
<div class="title" id=<?php the_ID(); ?> ></div>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID

Answer (score -1):

us an id

```
<div id="someidOne"></div>

<div id="someidTwo"></div>
```